# Is it possible to save an empty value for an integer type in gremlin

Tags: graphql, gremlin, tinkerpop

```
g.V(123).property('myProperty', myproperty? myProperty: null)
```

Here `myProperty` is of integer type and I wish to save an empty value for 'myProperty'.

I know null is not supported. Is there another alternative to achieve the same? (I can't save the value as 0 either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no notion of `null` in TinkerPop ([for now](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2235)) I'm afraid that you either have to remove the property or define some sort of constant to represent it. You say that you can't use "zero" but perhaps you could use something like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or something? Or, if you are using a graph that doesn't have an explicit schema you could set it to a non-integer value like a "null" string? I can't reall think of any other workarounds.